# Is it possible to exactly generate n number of clock pulses at half the clock frequency of the Atmega328p?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, clock, atmega328p, bit-bang

Let the problem be to exactly generate n clock pulses at half the clock frequency of the Atmel Atmega328p (datasheet [here](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf)).

To generate a PWM at a prescaled clock frequency of the Atmel Amega328p, we need to properly set up the registers of the 8-bit timer and the counting sequence. See the image below, where the PWM at pin OCnA/OCnB is generated using the time counter TCNTn and a comparator against the register OCRnA/OCRnB.

[image: Waveform generation based on the microcontroller's clock frequency with prescaler.]

Next, assume that we need to generate a very precise number of clock pulses to communicate with a peripheral. For instance, in the image below, we need to generate **exactly** 22 pulses to send to and acquire data from the chip. The 5 first bits are the command sent to the chip, and the 16 last bits are the data received from the chip.

[image: Generation of 22 pulses to communicate with a chip.]

In principle, if the message size is a multiple of 8 bits, we can directly use the SPI hardware/interface to communicate with the chip. The SPI module is directly wired in hardware using an 8-bit shift register (see image below).

[image: SPI description using byte-sized data.]

However, in our case, 22 is not a multiple of 8, so we should set things up manually. My idea was to generate 22 clock pulses using interrupt service routines (ISR), but I realized that I was not able to stop the timer instantaneously because the instruction takes several clock cycles from the CPU to reach out to the waveform generator. Recall that our PWM works at half the speed of the microcontroller, so any instruction that is longer than a clock pulse will result in a noticeable delay. In fact, I've noticed that there were always more than 22 pulses on the oscilloscope using this method.

Is it correct to say that it is just **impossible** to generate exactly 22 clock pulses at half the frequency of the microcontroller using the CPU (neither in C nor Assembler)? I think it's due to the fact that stopping the clock would take several clock cycles from the CPU (need to reach out to the correct register to stop the clock). Is it correct to say that generating 22 clock pulses at half of the microcontroller clock speed can **only be done in specialized hardware**?

The only solution I could think of in software is to **bit bang** the clock manually for 5 pulses (way slower than the microcontroller's clock frequency) then use the SPI hardware to read the 2-byte data. Do you have any idea if there is a better way to do so at the microcontroller's clock speed?

For your reference, I paste my Arduino code here to show you that we cannot generate exactly 22 clock pulses.

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile unsigned long count = 0;

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  count++;
  if (count == 21)
  {
    TCCR1B = 0x00; // Stop clock.
  }
}

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(115200);

  cli(); // Disable global interrupts.

  TCCR1A = 0x00; // Initialize TCCR1A register to 0.
  TCCR1B = 0x00; // Initialize TTCR1B register to 0.

  TCNT1 = 0; // Initialize time counter to 0.
  OCR1A = 1; // Duty cycle 50%.
  TCCR1A = bit(COM1A0); // Set OC1A on compare match.
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12); // CTC mode.
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // Enable timer compare interrupt.
  
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);

  sei(); // Enable all interrupts.

  Serial.println("Wait 1s..."); 
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Start PWM"); 
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10); // No prescaler.
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(count);
  delay(200);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at the microcontroller's clock speed"? I'm not aware of any possibility to generate signals at the same speed as the CPU clock in an Atmega328.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes you are right, it is half the speed of the CPU clock. I've corrected it in my post.

Comment: These are two different problems: "exactly generate n clock pulses at half the clock frequency" [implied: and nothing else], and "...to communicate with a peripheral". Which one is it?

Comment: In fact, the end purpose is to communicate with a peripheral. I know that there is no lower bound for the clock signal, so we can use a bit-bang strategy and that's it. But I wanted to know if it's possible to sync the data transmission with 1/2 or 1/4 the speed of the internal clock speed. Also from a theoretical perspective, is it possible to generate exactly those n clock pulses? When trying to use ISR and stop the timer, it takes some instruction cycles and I have more pulses than wanted. Just to know if it's technically possible to do so in software.

Comment: @TimWilliams Also, I tried to see how the SPI library works in Arduino. Here is the link of the source code: https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/libraries/SPI/src/SPI.h . As seen, the clock generated by the SPI library can go up to half the speed of the CPU clock, but everything is handled in hardware using the 8-bit shift register. I was just wondering if it's possible to do the same in software using assembler using simple ISR. But do I understand well that it's just impossible because just stopping the timer takes, say, 5 clock cycles?

Comment: If it's for the AS5134 in particular, and the ATMEGA is running at maximum rate of 20MHz, the 6MHz max clock rate would be violated. 1/4 or less must be used, or a lower F_CLK. I also don't see any indication it would be bothered by extra bits. Either send three byte transactions, or one byte and two 7-bit bytes.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have also thought of the 3 byte transactions but I was wondering the following. The first 5 bits are sent from the microcontroller, and the next 16 bits are received from the chip. If we send 8 zero bits, the 5 first bits are understood as the command. Next, the chip will send 3 bits following from this. Are they lost? Next, we send 2 bytes of zero and the chip send the rest of the message. We have at the end 3 flapping clock pulses, which are understood as the next command. I have the impression that this shift will be propagated and difficult to handle. Not sure if I'm correct

Comment: Oh right, it automatically switches direction. Well, can always wire a resistor between MOSI and MISO, and soft-drive it that way. Also, checking, neither SPI module has other than 8-bits so you'd have to [ab]use the USART synchronous mode, swapping RX/TX midway (again, a resistor would be easiest, making it automatic). Baud generator is max  F_CPU/2 in sync mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139724/discussion-between-tim-williams-and-chckx592).

Answer (score 0):

A simpler example: The clock is the fastest signal per def on your system, so if you're piping out bits from a shift register (22 pulses is 0101... aka 0xA repeated 11 times followed by zeroes) Each bit shift will happen at the rising edge of the clock. Because one pulse is the 0-1 part, the pulses will be at exactly HALF the clock frequency. QED.

Besides, signals happening at the same frequency as the clock in a digital system is super problematic, as logic stops to work with hold/setup times violated.

You could also think of the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem, from a theory perspective. You always need your system to clock at least twice as fast as your fastest changing external signal.

Now this does not even begin to take into account the issues of peripherials and synchronizing digital signals, which might introduce significant latency into the system.

In other words, no.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake in my statement. It should be half the speed of the CPU clock. I've corrected it in my original post.

Comment: That would be 0xA repeated 5 and a half times, not 11 times.